# Multiple authors, single email

Tags: org-mode

I have a situation where there is one primary author and a few more secondary authors.  I only want to specify the email of the primary author, but it gets appended to the last author mentioned.

Beside the original question: is there a better way of specifying multiple authors than:

```
#+author: First author, \\ second author \\ etc.
```

This line gets too long when you need to specify the titles of people involved.  It also interferes with the generated table of contents.

Comment: Are you exporting this? Which exporter? If not, what do you want to do with the org file?

Comment: @zck yes, exporting to LaTeX -> PDF. I was hoping there would be a way to split this long line into multiple lines, but repeating `#+author:` line doesn't work: only the last one gets exported.